# Does .one domain extension supports the URS procedure

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I was wondering if the .one domain extension supports the
Uniform Rapid Suspension (URS) or Uniform Domain-Name Dispute-Resolution Policy (UDRP) procedure.

Comment: Why don't you get the authoritative answer at https://www.one.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would appear that the `.one` TLD supports these procedures. The [domain registration agreement](https://www.one.com/en/domain-registration-agreement) says:

> #### 8. Applicable policies and domain name disputes
>
> 8.1 You agree to be bound by all ICANN consensus policies and all policies of any relevant registry operator, including but not limited to the [Uniform Rapid Suspension Procedure ("URS")](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/urs) and the [Uniform Domain Name Dispute Resolution policy ("UDRP")](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/help/dndr/udrp-en). ICANN may change these rules at any time.

Answer (score 2):

URS is mandatory for all gTLDs per ICANN rules.

Specification 7, §2 of master registry agreement with ICANN for any gTLDs at https://newgtlds.icann.org/sites/default/files/agreements/agreement-approved-09jan14-en.htm :

> 2. Dispute Resolution Mechanisms.  Registry Operator will comply with the following dispute resolution mechanisms as they may be revised from time to time:
>
> a.              the Trademark Post-Delegation Dispute Resolution Procedure (PDDRP) and the Registration Restriction Dispute Resolution Procedure (RRDRP) [..]
>
> b. the Uniform Rapid Suspension system (“URS”) adopted by ICANN (posted at http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registries/urs), including the implementation of determinations issued by URS examiner

UDRP is mostly a registrar matter, and yes also per ICANN agreements all registrars accredited in gTLDs have to follow the UDRP.